# What would be the best option to display class properties in a Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid?

Tags: c#, uwp, datatable, windows-community-toolkit

Simplifying my case, basically, I have the following classes where Types are read from a DB:

```
public class Type1
    {
        public int Property1 { get; set; }
        public int Property2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Type2
    {
        public int Property3 { get; set; }
        public int Property4 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Info
    {
        public Type1 Type1 { get; set; }
        public Type2 Type2 { get; set; }
    }
```

What I would like to do, is display the name and value of each Type property in a DataGrid using the Info class. What approach should I choose to do this?

My idea was to create a DataTable from the Info class and use that as an input for the DataGrid. Would this be the best approach?

Comment: Could you explain how the result should look like?

Comment: Sure! The result table should have the following columns: Property1, Property2, Property3, Property4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the best approach would be to create a class with a property per column (name and value) that you want to display in the `DataGrid` and then create instances of this class based on your existing type data.

You should transform your data model into a view model that the `DataGrid` understands how to present on the screen.